# Music player with labelled regions or time markers

Tags: music-player

Do you know a music player that allows to add labels to parts of the audio file so later on I can easily find the region and play just that part of the audio file?(Like in Audacity.)

Or at least time-markers?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way: a simple html document using the html5 audio tag opened in the readily available Android Browser is sufficient for my modest needs.